# Trying to vertical align content inside article but cannot figure it out

Tags: html, css

Trying to vertical align content inside article but cannot figure it out. I have tried using table and vertical align, but cannot seem to get it to work. I am open to anything though. I just want it to be responsive and centered perfectly within the right hand side.

The left part obviously has an image in. I don't know how to insert it. It fits nicely in a line but don't understand how to vertically align the contents in article.

If someone could help m eout that would be amazing! Thank you :)

```css
#employee-profile {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

#employee-profile-info {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: .5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

:nth-child(5) {
  background: red;
  width: 10%;
}

:nth-child(6) {
  background: yellow;
  width: calc(90% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="employee-profile">
    <img src="img/pic1.jpeg" alt="pic1">
    
    <div id="employee-profile-info">
      <article class="info">
          <h3>Cameron Walker </h3>

          <h4>Associate Consultant</h4>

          <a href="/consultants/cameron-walker"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i> View consultant jobs</a>

          <a href="mailto:cameron.walker@twentyrecruitment.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>cameron.walker@twentyrecruitment.com</a>

          <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/cameron-walker-63a73793/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true">In</i></a>

          <a href="tel:+44 203 189 4317"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>+44 203 189 4317</a>

          <p class="custom-scroll mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1"> Cameron started at Twenty in August 2017 following the completion of his degree in English from the University of Nottingham.&nbsp;</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want Cameron Walker text vertically align?. Your css is wrong

Comment: I want everything within #employee-profile-info to be vertically aligned. But I want the <img> container to be the same size as the employee info container.

Comment: let me edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want?
Remove height from the `#employee-profile-info`

```css
#employee-profile {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

#employee-profile-info {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: .5s;
}

a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

:nth-child(5) {
  background: red;
  width: 10%;
}

:nth-child(6) {
  background: yellow;
  width: calc(90% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="employee-profile">
    <img src="img/pic1.jpeg" alt="pic1">
    
    <div id="employee-profile-info">
      <article class="info">
          <h3>Cameron Walker </h3>

          <h4>Associate Consultant</h4>

          <a href="/consultants/cameron-walker"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i> View consultant jobs</a>

          <a href="mailto:cameron.walker@twentyrecruitment.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>cameron.walker@twentyrecruitment.com</a>

          <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/cameron-walker-63a73793/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true">In</i></a>

          <a href="tel:+44 203 189 4317"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>+44 203 189 4317</a>

          <p class="custom-scroll mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1"> Cameron started at Twenty in August 2017 following the completion of his degree in English from the University of Nottingham.&nbsp;</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I want it to be the same size as the image however. So unfortunately this still doesn't work. The image is just a perfect square. I'm super grateful of the help though, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you. Let me know any issue if you have